# The default keybinding for opening a terminal in dwm does not work

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminal, dwm

I'm new to dwm (suckless.org) and also to GNU/Linux. I know a bit of the C language but don't really understand the `config.h` file.

#### SYS-CONFIG

I use Ubuntu 18.04 (installed with netinstaller + vanilla gnome...) and recently I wanted to try **dwm 6.2**.

#### HOW I INSTALLED IT

I downloaded the `tar.gz` file from the suckless.org website and for install I just typed `make` in terminal in that folder (without any error) and I also installed the dwm via Ubuntu repository and finally created a symbolic link in `~/bin/` thereafter, I created a `.xinitrc` in home folder and put `exec dwm` in that. then I rebooted, and logged in. I didn't change the config file.

#### PROBLEM

The default keybinding, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't open `gnome-terminal`.

#### config.h

```
/* key definitions */
#define MODKEY Mod1Mask
#define TAGKEYS(KEY,TAG) \
    { MODKEY,                       KEY,      view,           {.ui = 1 << TAG} }, \
    { MODKEY|ControlMask,           KEY,      toggleview,     {.ui = 1 << TAG} }, \
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             KEY,      tag,            {.ui = 1 << TAG} }, \
    { MODKEY|ControlMask|ShiftMask, KEY,      toggletag,      {.ui = 1 << TAG} },

/* helper for spawning shell commands in the pre dwm-5.0 fashion */
#define SHCMD(cmd) { .v = (const char*[]){ "/bin/sh", "-c", cmd, NULL } }

/* commands */
static char dmenumon[2] = "0"; /* component of dmenucmd, manipulated in spawn() */
static const char *dmenucmd[] = { "dmenu_run", "-m", dmenumon, "-fn", dmenufont, "-nb", col_gray1, "-nf", col_gray3, "-sb", col_cyan, "-sf", col_gray4, NULL };
static const char *termcmd[]  = { "st", NULL };

static Key keys[] = {
    /* modifier                     key        function        argument */
    { MODKEY,                       XK_p,      spawn,          {.v = dmenucmd } },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_Return, spawn,          {.v = termcmd } },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_b,      togglebar,      {0} },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_j,      focusstack,     {.i = +1 } },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_k,      focusstack,     {.i = -1 } },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_i,      incnmaster,     {.i = +1 } },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_d,      incnmaster,     {.i = -1 } },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_h,      setmfact,       {.f = -0.05} },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_l,      setmfact,       {.f = +0.05} },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_Return, zoom,           {0} },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_Tab,    view,           {0} },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_c,      killclient,     {0} },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_t,      setlayout,      {.v = &layouts[0]} },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_f,      setlayout,      {.v = &layouts[1]} },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_m,      setlayout,      {.v = &layouts[2]} },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_space,  setlayout,      {0} },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_space,  togglefloating, {0} },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_0,      view,           {.ui = ~0 } },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_0,      tag,            {.ui = ~0 } },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_comma,  focusmon,       {.i = -1 } },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_period, focusmon,       {.i = +1 } },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_comma,  tagmon,         {.i = -1 } },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_period, tagmon,         {.i = +1 } },
    TAGKEYS(                        XK_1,                      0)
    TAGKEYS(                        XK_2,                      1)
    TAGKEYS(                        XK_3,                      2)
    TAGKEYS(                        XK_4,                      3)
    TAGKEYS(                        XK_5,                      4)
    TAGKEYS(                        XK_6,                      5)
    TAGKEYS(                        XK_7,                      6)
    TAGKEYS(                        XK_8,                      7)
    TAGKEYS(                        XK_9,                      8)
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_q,      quit,           {0} },
};
```

Comment: The proper way to install suckless software is to `make` then `make install` so you don't have to symlink manually the binary. Could you please provide the "key definitions" and "commands" sections of your `config.h` file?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful edit. I'm new to this kinds of websites. How can I post it here? copy paste the whole thing in the comments or attach the file?

Comment: Just edit your question by pasting the desired sections of the file. Make sure to use code syntax highlighting to have a proper formatting.

Comment: thanks man. I post those lines that you've mentioned.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the default terminal from `st` to `gnome-terminal`. I learned how to ask more properly. this was my first question. thank you Loic!!!

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stack Exchange. Don't forget to mark the [answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/794983) by clicking the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem:

> `static const char *termcmd[]  = { "st", NULL };`

The `dwm` build from suckless.org uses `st` as default terminal emulator therefore <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is mapped to `st` which is not installed on your system. You  need to change `st` to `gnome-terminal` or whatever other terminal emulator you want (and which is installed on your system).

Once you edited the configuration file run `make` and `make install` to apply the changes to your system.

Answer (score 1):

In default config.h of dwm, there are two lines involved to execute a terminal:

`static const char *termcmd[]  = { "rxvt", NULL };`
I use `rxvt`, you can change it to `gnome-terminal`

`{ MODKEY, XK_Return, spawn, {.v = termcmd } },`
Which sets the keyboard shortcut to constant `termcmd`. In my case it's just <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Also, as noted in comments, you should compile dwn, `sudo make clean install`. Only after compiling, changes of `config.h` are applied (there are patches of dwm to overcome this). You can edit `config.mk` before compliling if you like, for example to change path of executables.

Comment: It worked. I should've change the default terminal. It's a bit strange, cause I remember I installed `st` via repository but it didn't work too. I guess I should read and study source code (I guess I'm too dump for dwm now :) ). again thanks man!!!

Comment: @alibb if you installed  `st` from Ubuntu repositories you need to change `st` to `stterm`.